# Comparing with csv file value

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, csv

I have a csv file and I need to compare the value in 4th column of 2nd row with a string.

Sample csv file:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
Val1,Val2,Val3,ValNeeded
```

I'm using the below code to perform this,

```bsh
varcsv=`sed '2q;d' file.csv | cut -d',' -f4 | tr -d ' '`

myvar=ValNeeded

if [ "$varcsv" = "$myvar" ]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

Output of this code is `false` and the length of `varcsv` is `10` (even the length is incorrect).

Please let me know where the change is required.

Comment: If your `cat´ version supports the `-v` option, please share the output of `cat -v file.csv`

Comment: Who is deleting comments and why?

Comment: convert your .csv file from windows to unix text file format with `fromdos`.  or if you don't have that installed, you can use `perl -i -p -e 's/\r\n/\n/' filename.csv`

Comment: Philippos, I'm seeing ^M at the end

Comment: Cas, the perl worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical problem with files that have MSDOS line endings (carriage return + line feed). The carriage return is invisible, but will be part of the string to compare.

You already discovered the length is wrong and I suppose your `tr -d ' '` was intended to remove a trailing space, but the problem was not a whitespace. Just add a carriage return to your `tr` argument (enter it by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>. It will show as `tr -d ' ^M'`.

Comment: Philippos, this is not helpong either.

Comment: I had one more observation that if I try to append at the end of anything to the csv output, it's getting appensed at the start. Like: ```abc${varcsv}__def``` Output: ```__deflNeeded```

Comment: that's not anything being "appended at the start".  That's the carriage return at the end of `$varcsv` returning the cursor to the beginning of the line when the string is printed, then continuing with `__def`.  That's what CR does, it's what it's for, it's **why** it's called "Carriage **Return**".   the name goes back to old mechanical typewriters and teletypes and the like.

Comment: try piping the output into `cat -A` or `cat -v` or `hexdump`.  you'll see the ^M in the middle of cat's output (or hex 0d in the case of hexdump).

Comment: Yea I'm seeing ^M at the end

Answer (score 1):

While I posted my answer as a comment and comments were removed, let's give it another shot:

The way you are approaching it is OK but can be improved in such a way that you won't need the dependency on too many external binaries. For example, to solve your issue you can use `awk` as follows:

```
awk -F, -vmyvar="ValNeeded" 'NR==2 { if ($4 == myvar) print "match"; else print "No match"}'  file.csv
```

If you want to keep your code but rewrite it slightly it'd look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

varcsv=$(awk -F, 'NR==2 { print $NF }' file.csv)
myvar=ValNeeded
if [[ $varcsv == "$myvar" ]]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

The `$NF` there gets the last field in the record.

As it was already mentioned by Philippos, your file contains MSDOS line endings, a.k.a CR/LF.
You can check those in different ways using, `cat`, `sed`, `od` and many other tools but let's keep it simple and use `cat` and `sed` in this case:

`cat -vEt file.csv` or `sed -n l file.csv`

This will return something like:

```
Val1,Val2,Val3,SomeVar^M$
Val1,Val2,Val3,ValNeeded^M$
Val1,Val2,Val3,Ignorevar^M$
$
```

To remove these `^M$` charachters all together, you can use some utils. For example:
`dos2unix file.csv`. There are other ways to do it from within the editor but that requires more effort.

Once you've converted the file you should be good.